# Itext7 CellRenderer does not always work

Tags: java, itext7

I'm using Itext7 to create a pdf with a table in it.
The table occupies multiple pages.
I'm also overriding the cell renderer to add a formfield to some cell.
I noticed that when the table goes to a new page the first line doesn't trigger the draw method of the CellRender class.
I put some code below for better understanding.

```
...
//adding the cells to table
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    addRow(table,i);
}
...
//addRow implementation
private void addRow(Table table, int row) throws IOException {
    table.startNewRow();

    PdfFont zapfdingbats = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.ZAPFDINGBATS);

    Cell checkBoxCell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("o").setFont(zapfdingbats).setMargins(9, 0, 0, 11)).setKeepTogether(true);
    checkBoxCell.setNextRenderer(new CheckboxCellRenderer(checkBoxCell, "cb"+row));
    table.addCell(checkBoxCell);
    ...
    //other cells here
}
...
//The implementation of the custom CellRender
protected class CheckboxCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
    protected String name;

    public CheckboxCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, String name) {
        super(modelElement);
        this.name = name;
    }
    //this method is not triggered for the first row when a new page is created
    @Override
    public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
        System.out.println(name);
        super.draw(drawContext);
        float x = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft();
        float y = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom();
        float width = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getRight()-getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft();
        float height = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getTop()-getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom();
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x+5, y+5, width-10, height-10);
        PdfTextFormField pdfTextFormField = PdfFormField.createText(drawContext.getDocument(), rect, name);
        PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(drawContext.getDocument(), true).addField(pdfTextFormField);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you go to a new page, then your `Renderer` is discarded and a new `Renderer` object is created. This is done in order to avoid muddying up the state in case something changes in the model object. In this case, the method `getNextRenderer` is called:

```
/**
 * Gets a new instance of this class to be used as a next renderer, after this renderer is used, if
 * {@link #layout(LayoutContext)} is called more than once.
 * @return new renderer instance
 */
IRenderer getNextRenderer();
```

So you should be OK if you just override this method in your custom `CheckboxCellRenderer` class:

```
@Override
public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
    return new CheckboxCellRenderer(getModelElement(), name);
}
```

Comment: Hello, could you please check my question, because I am using this approach and didn't helped... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792667/setnextrenderer-doesnt-trigger-draw-method-for-renderer-in-itext7

Answer (score 8):

You do not override one very important method: `public IRenderer getNextRenderer()`.

If a cell cannot be placed on a page, iText creates an overflow cell (see `protected AbstractRenderer createOverflowRenderer(int layoutResult)` method. If you do not override `getNextRenderer` iText by default will create simple CellRenderer using its getModelElement().

So I suggest you should add summat: 

            `@Override
            public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
                return new CheckboxCellRenderer(getModelElement(), name);
            }`

I've created the next sample using your code and it works as you expect.
`

```
public class ArrayToTable extends GenericTest {
public static final String DEST = "./target/test/resources/sandbox/tables/array_to_table.pdf";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    new CustomRendererTest().manipulatePdf(DEST);
}

@Override
protected void manipulatePdf(String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

    Table table = new Table(1);
    //adding the cells to table
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        addRow(table, i);
    }

    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
}

    //addRow implementation
    private void addRow(Table table, int row) throws IOException {
        table.startNewRow();

        PdfFont zapfdingbats = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.ZAPFDINGBATS);

        Cell checkBoxCell = new Cell().add(new Paragraph("o").setFont(zapfdingbats).setMargins(9, 0, 0, 11)).setKeepTogether(true);
        checkBoxCell.setNextRenderer(new CheckboxCellRenderer(checkBoxCell, "cb"+row));
        table.addCell(checkBoxCell);
        //other cells here
    }

    //The implementation of the custom CellRender
    protected class CheckboxCellRenderer extends CellRenderer {
        protected String name;

        public CheckboxCellRenderer(Cell modelElement, String name) {
            super(modelElement);
            this.name = name;
        }
        //this method is not triggered for the first row when a new page is created
        @Override
        public void draw(DrawContext drawContext) {
            System.out.println(name);
            super.draw(drawContext);
            float x = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft();
            float y = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom();
            float width = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getRight()-getOccupiedAreaBBox().getLeft();
            float height = getOccupiedAreaBBox().getTop()-getOccupiedAreaBBox().getBottom();
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x+5, y+5, width-10, height-10);
            PdfTextFormField pdfTextFormField = PdfFormField.createText(drawContext.getDocument(), rect, name);
            PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(drawContext.getDocument(), true).addField(pdfTextFormField);
        }

        @Override
        public IRenderer getNextRenderer() {
            return new CheckboxCellRenderer(getModelElement(), name);
        }

    }
```

}
`

Comment: Please look at this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63792667/setnextrenderer-doesnt-trigger-draw-method-for-renderer-in-itext7